# "Unfortunately, app name has stopped." android device or emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new in android development and I'm following some tutorials to create the first apps.
When I want to run the app, compiler shows no error but in Emulator shows "Unfortunately, Viewfinder blabla has stopped."

The code:

**AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          package="com.example.viewfinderee368" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0">

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
                 android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".ViewfinderEE368" 
                  android:label="@string/app_name" 
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape">

                 <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                 </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="6"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

</manifest>
```

**src/.java file**

```
package com.example.viewfinderee368;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class ViewfinderEE368 extends Activity {    
    private Preview mPreview;
    private DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        // Create our DrawOnTop view.
        mDrawOnTop = new DrawOnTop(this);
        mPreview = new Preview(this, mDrawOnTop);
        setContentView(mPreview);
        addContentView(mDrawOnTop, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class DrawOnTop extends View {
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Paint mPaintBlack;
    Paint mPaintYellow;
    Paint mPaintRed;
    Paint mPaintGreen;
    Paint mPaintBlue;
    byte[] mYUVData;
    int[] mRGBData;
    int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
    int[] mRedHistogram;
    int[] mGreenHistogram;
    int[] mBlueHistogram;
    double[] mBinSquared;

    public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mPaintBlack = new Paint();
        mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaintBlack.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintYellow = new Paint();
        mPaintYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mPaintYellow.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintRed = new Paint();
        mPaintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintRed.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaintRed.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintGreen = new Paint();
        mPaintGreen.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaintGreen.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintBlue = new Paint();
        mPaintBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaintBlue.setTextSize(25);

        mBitmap = null;
        mYUVData = null;
        mRGBData = null;
        mRedHistogram = new int[256];
        mGreenHistogram = new int[256];
        mBlueHistogram = new int[256];
        mBinSquared = new double[256];
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            mBinSquared[bin] = ((double)bin) * bin;
        } // bin
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBitmap != null)
        {
            int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
            int newImageWidth = canvasWidth;
            int newImageHeight = canvasHeight;
            int marginWidth = (canvasWidth - newImageWidth)/2;

            // Convert from YUV to RGB
            decodeYUV420SP(mRGBData, mYUVData, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

            // Draw bitmap
//          mBitmap.setPixels(mRGBData, 0, mImageWidth, 0, 0, 
//                  mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
//          Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
//          Rect dst = new Rect(marginWidth, 0, 
//                  canvasWidth-marginWidth, canvasHeight);
//          canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, mPaintBlack);

            // Draw black borders                       
//          canvas.drawRect(0, 0, marginWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);
//          canvas.drawRect(canvasWidth - marginWidth, 0, 
//                  canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);

            // Calculate histogram
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mRedHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 0);
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mGreenHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 1);
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mBlueHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 2);

            // Calculate mean
            double imageRedMean = 0, imageGreenMean = 0, imageBlueMean = 0;
            double redHistogramSum = 0, greenHistogramSum = 0, blueHistogramSum = 0;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                imageRedMean += mRedHistogram[bin] * bin;
                redHistogramSum += mRedHistogram[bin];
                imageGreenMean += mGreenHistogram[bin] * bin;
                greenHistogramSum += mGreenHistogram[bin];
                imageBlueMean += mBlueHistogram[bin] * bin;
                blueHistogramSum += mBlueHistogram[bin];
            } // bin
            imageRedMean /= redHistogramSum;
            imageGreenMean /= greenHistogramSum;
            imageBlueMean /= blueHistogramSum;

            // Calculate second moment
            double imageRed2ndMoment = 0, imageGreen2ndMoment = 0, imageBlue2ndMoment = 0;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                imageRed2ndMoment += mRedHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                imageGreen2ndMoment += mGreenHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                imageBlue2ndMoment += mBlueHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
            } // bin
            imageRed2ndMoment /= redHistogramSum;
            imageGreen2ndMoment /= greenHistogramSum;
            imageBlue2ndMoment /= blueHistogramSum;
            double imageRedStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageRed2ndMoment - imageRedMean*imageRedMean );
            double imageGreenStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageGreen2ndMoment - imageGreenMean*imageGreenMean );
            double imageBlueStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageBlue2ndMoment - imageBlueMean*imageBlueMean );

            // Draw mean
            String imageMeanStr = "Mean (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueMean);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10, 30, mPaintYellow);

            // Draw standard deviation
            String imageStdDevStr = "Std Dev (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueStdDev);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10, 60, mPaintYellow);

            // Draw red intensity histogram
            float barMaxHeight = 3000;
            float barWidth = ((float)newImageWidth) / 256;
            float barMarginHeight = 2;
            RectF barRect = new RectF();
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 200;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                float prob = (float)mRedHistogram[bin] / (float)redHistogramSum;
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - 
                    Math.min(80,prob*barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintRed);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin

            // Draw green intensity histogram
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 100;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mGreenHistogram[bin])/((float)greenHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGreen);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin

            // Draw blue intensity histogram
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mBlueHistogram[bin])/((float)blueHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlue);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin
        } // end if statement

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    } // end onDraw method

    static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
        }
    }

    static public void decodeYUV420SPGrayscale(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height)
    {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int pix = 0; pix < frameSize; pix++)
        {
            int pixVal = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[pix])) - 16;
            if (pixVal < 0) pixVal = 0;
            if (pixVal > 255) pixVal = 255;
            rgb[pix] = 0xff000000 | (pixVal << 16) | (pixVal << 8) | pixVal;
        } // pix
    }

    static public void calculateIntensityHistogram(int[] rgb, int[] histogram, int width, int height, int component)
    {
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            histogram[bin] = 0;
        } // bin
        if (component == 0) // red
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 16) & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
        else if (component == 1) // green
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 8) & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
        else // blue
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = rgb[pix] & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
    }
} 

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;
    DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;
    boolean mFinished;

    Preview(Context context, DrawOnTop drawOnTop) {
        super(context);

        mDrawOnTop = drawOnTop;
        mFinished = false;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

           // Preview callback used whenever new viewfinder frame is available
           mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
              public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
              {
                  if ( (mDrawOnTop == null) || mFinished )
                      return;

                  if (mDrawOnTop.mBitmap == null)
                  {
                      // Initialize the draw-on-top companion
                      Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;
                      mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth, 
                              mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                      mDrawOnTop.mRGBData = new int[mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth * mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight]; 
                      mDrawOnTop.mYUVData = new byte[data.length];                    
                  }

                  // Pass YUV data to draw-on-top companion
                  System.arraycopy(data, 0, mDrawOnTop.mYUVData, 0, data.length);
                  mDrawOnTop.invalidate();
              }
           });
        } 
        catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        mFinished = true;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(15);
        parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

}
```

I tried to run the app both in Emulator and real device and the error was the same.

Thanks!

edit:
**LogCat**

```
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.viewfinderee368/com.example.viewfinderee368.ViewfinderEE368}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:215)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3225)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at com.example.viewfinderee368.ViewfinderEE368.onCreate(ViewfinderEE368.java:52)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
11-20 02:50:38.943: E/AndroidRuntime(614):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: That's a really long piece of code. Why don't you give us the stack trace (in red) in Logcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have the `setContentView()` line next to `super.onCreate(savedInstance)`

```
  setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_filename);
```

Always call `setContentView()` before initializing any UI component, Otherwise you will get Issues.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are new to Android. I would strongly recommend you to go through

[this link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html). It has good amount of tutorials and will surely help.

For the problem you have, it is because there is no layout specified in the Activity. To understand what an Activity is, go through the Android tutorials at the link above, or at developer.android.com

Answer (score 1):

change your android version code and version name to currently using version code and name.

I also faced same issue in the beginning, but it was resolved..